# SharePoint Online document library shows null when retrieving filename

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-online, powershell, online

I'm accessing a SharePoint Online document library using the following:

```
## <redacted boilerplace> ##
# Get the Client Context and Bind the Site Collection
$context = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext($siteroot + $sitesubsite)

# Authenticate
$credentials = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SharePointOnlineCredentials($AdminUsername, $AdminPassword)
$context.Credentials = $credentials

# Lookup Source Address 
$rootWeb = $Context.Web
$List = $rootWeb.lists.getByTitle($ListName)
$fields = $List.Fields;
$ListItems = $List.GetItems([Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.CamlQuery]::CreateAllItemsQuery())
# Load the List
$Context.Load($rootWeb)
$Context.Load($List)
$Context.Load($ListItems)
$Context.Load($fields)
$Context.ExecuteQuery()

# create a hastable of listdata for casting into JSON
$listArray = New-Object System.Collections.Generic.List[System.Object]
foreach ($item in $ListItems)
{   
    $listArray.Add([hashtable]@{
        Filename = $item["Name"];
        DisplayTitle=$item["Title"].ToString(); 
        Settings= $item["Setting"]; 
        Description= $item["File_x0020_Description"];
        HealthAreas= $item["Health_x0020_Area"]; 
        ResourceType= $item["Resource_x0020_Type"]; 
        Active= $item["Currently_x0020_active_x003f_"];     
        ExternalURL= $item["External_x0020_file_x0020_path"]; 
    })
}
```

When I use `Write-Host` to print the results to the screen the `Filename` returns as null.

I've also attempted to use `$item.AttachmentFiles.Path;` and `$item.File.LinkingUrl` however both return null results.

I thought potentially this could be stored in AttachmentFiles (even though document libraries are a 1:1 relationship with files) and did `$item.AttachmentFiles.Count;` which also returned a null value.

Searching online indicates that I should use `item.Name` for this however that isn't available within my object and the resources don't appear to address SharePoint Online (most are from on-premise 2010).

I'm sure it's something simple I'm missing, but what element should I be using to access the filename for the files within my SharePoint Online document library?

Comment: Try it as `Filename = $item["FileLeafRef"];`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be using `Filename = $item["FileLeafRef"];` ([documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spbuiltinfieldid.fileleafref.aspx))

Try it as below:

```
$listArray.Add([hashtable]@{
        Filename = $item["FileLeafRef"];
        DisplayTitle=$item["Title"].ToString(); 
        Settings= $item["Setting"]; 
        Description= $item["File_x0020_Description"];
        HealthAreas= $item["Health_x0020_Area"]; 
        ResourceType= $item["Resource_x0020_Type"]; 
        Active= $item["Currently_x0020_active_x003f_"];     
        ExternalURL= $item["External_x0020_file_x0020_path"]; 
    })
```